# Load page with nightmare

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, nightmare

problematic url: https://play.livebet.com/#/sport/?lang=pol&type=0&competition=1978&region=1840001&game=15068229&sport=1

I created a node js script to fetch data from the link above.
It was working fine for 2 days and then nightmare couldn't load the content anymore.

After 40 seconds timeout is thrown. It should take 2 seconds at most.
When I run it I can see it is loading it forever.

here is the code snippet:

```
function fetchMatches(key, url) {
    new Nightmare({
        show: true,
        waitTimeout: 40000,
        webPreferences: {
          partition: 'nopersist'
        }
    })
      .goto(url)
      .wait(function() {
        var dd = document.evaluate("(//div[contains(@class, 'multicolumn-table')])[2]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

        if (dd.iterateNext() == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
      })
      .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('body').innerHTML)
      .end()
      .then(response => {
        var fs = require("fs");
        fs.appendFileSync('livebet.txt', 'Processing');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Search failed:', error)
      })
}
```

I don't understand what happened and why it is not able to do it. When I open this link in my browser I can see the content loaded.

Does anybody know what can be the problem here?

Comment: You might want to switch to puppeteer, not a lot of people are still using nightmarejs

Comment: Will puppeteer solve this issue? I already tried htmlunit and selenium in java with the same effect. Actually I think I tried puppeteer too